# Div width is like width of page for some reason

Tags: html, css

I have a page with some divs there.
HTML:

```
<div class="utilitiesHeader">
    <div id="utilitiesLogo"></div>
    <div id="utilitiesFIO">Name of user</div>
</div>
<div class="utilitiesContent">
    <div class="utilitiesCommon">Comon</div>
    <div class="utilitiesArchive">Archive</div>
    <div class="utilitiesReadings">Readings</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#utilitiesLogo {
    width: 226px;
    height: 101px;
    background: url("../images/feelinhome-logo.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    margin: 0;
}
div#utilitiesFIO {
    float:right;
    font-size: 30px;
}
div.utilitiesHeader {
    display:inline;
}
```

As you can see in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cddpdg0r/1/) div with Name for some reason is on the other string and logo div is in width of all page, however I give it certain width. What's the reason?

Comment: maybe you should add `display: inline` to `div#utilitiesLogo`?  http://jsfiddle.net/cddpdg0r/2/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I dont get the problem what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you set the utilitiesHeader with `display:inline` but: width does not apply to an inline element! - so the utilitiesHeader won't confine the elements according to the width of the utilitiesLogo (which has a set width)

See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-width) regarding the **width** property:

> Applies to:   all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table
>   rows, and row groups

To fix this set `display:inline-block` on the utilitiesHeader.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/cddpdg0r/4/)**